# unable to read the data from file in python

Tags: python

I am unable to read the data from file in python . Below is the sample code and Error which I am getting .

```
abc.txt has the value 2015-05-07

f = open("/opt/test/abc.txt","r")
f.read()
last_Exe_date = f.read()
f.close()
```

while reading the file(anc.txt) i am getting the error :   TypeError: argument 1 must be string or read-only character buffer, not file . i am not able to read the value into last_Exe_date from file(abc.txt) . could you please correct me if I am wrong with the code.

Comment: You're reading the file twice. Try removing the first f.read().

Comment: Please show the exact stacktrace of the error message. Currently it is not possible to pinpoint the source (line) of the error message.

Comment: Also why are you using semi colons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work fine:

```
f = open("/opt/test/abc.txt","r")
last_Exe_date = f.read()
f.close()
```

As was said, you had `f.read()` twice, so when you tried to store the contents into `last_Exe_date`, it would be empty.

You could also consider using the following method:

```
with open("/opt/test/abc.txt","r") as f:
    last_Exe_date = f.read()
```

This will ensure that the file is automatically closed afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

When you read a file once, the cursor is at the end of the file and you won't get anything more by re-reading it. Read through [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) to understand it more. And use `readline` to read a file line by line.

Oh, and remove the semicolon at the end of your `read` calls...